# apply rules in a list of files in GNU Make (or 'for' instruction in GNU Make)

Tags: make, gnu-make

I have this rules in my GNU Makefile:

```
FITXER = fitxa.md

$(FITXER).html: $(FITXER)
    pandoc --from markdown --to html $(FITXER) -o $(FITXER).html

$(FITXER).jpeg: $(FITXER).html
    wkhtmltoimage $(FITXER).html $(FITXER).jpeg
```

Is there any way to apply this rules in a list of files: for example something like that (in pseudocode):

```
for FITXER in [fitxa.md, a.md, b.md, ...] do

   $(FITXER).html: $(FITXER)
    pandoc --from markdown --to html $(FITXER) -o $(FITXER).html

   $(FITXER).jpeg: $(FITXER).html
    wkhtmltoimage $(FITXER).html $(FITXER).jpeg
endfor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go about this is to define general build rules:

```
%.html: %.md
    pandoc --from markdown --to html $< -o $@

%.jpg: %.html
    wkhtmltoimage $< $@
```

This tells `make` how to create HTML files from Markdown files, then how to create JPEGs from HTML files.

Once you've done that, all that's needed is to tell `make` all the *output* files you're after:

```
all: fitxa.jpg a.jpg b.jpg

.PHONY: all
```

`make all` will figure out what to do to obtain the requested JPEG files.

You can still define other rules to process specific Markdown files in a different way:

```
foo.jpg: foo.md
    # Process foo.md here to build foo.jpg
```

These specific rules take precedence over the generic rules.

Comment: Thanks but your example applies for *all* files with an extensions `.html` and `.md` but what about if you want to apply this rules just to some documents in our list? That is, perhaps `a.md` to `a.html` need a pandoc but `foo.md` need another tool. Don't I explain well? In my example I *just* want to apply to the files `fitxa.md`, `a.md` and `b.md`.

Comment: The example explains how to build an HTML file from a Markdown file, it doesn't apply to all files automatically. Make works backwards from the target, `all` in the example, so it only builds `fitxa.jpg`, `a.jpg` and `b.jpg`, regardless of what Markdown or HTML files are present. You can also specify other, non-generic rules for other files.

Comment: How can I do that? How make that non-generic rules are applied to foo.md for example?

Comment: See my update. May I suggest you read the [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/), it will help you understand how to write rules.

Comment: Although it is not exactly what I want, it works. I think there were control structures in Gnu Make (like for, if, etc.).

Comment: Yes, there are such control statements, but you don't need them for the problem as stated in your question. Make works better if you let it handle dependencies by using it declaratively instead of using it as a scripting language.